# Child component not re-rendering immediately when map of an array is used to create html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am in the process of making my first React-Flask app. I'll probably get murdered for my code as a beginner but here goes.

I tried to make a video to show the strange behavior. It only seems to happen when the child component maps an array of values to render the desired output

The parent state is updated immediately which you can see in the console log.

However the child component only updates when something else of the page is interacted with.

Link to youtube video to show the weirdness:

https://youtu.be/ysFdCiWr51E

in terms of code

The child component is made of two layers:

Upper child layer:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ReactComponent as FilterIcon } from '../icons/filter.svg';
import FilterColumnSelector from './filterSelector.js';

export default function FilterDropZone({
  filters,
  removeFilter,
  handleDraggedItem,
  namespace,
  handleAddFilter
}) {
  const handleDragOver = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(filters);
  }, [filters]);

  const handleDrop = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var columnName = event.dataTransfer.getData('text');

    console.log(columnName);
    if (columnName) {
      handleAddFilter(columnName);

      event.dataTransfer.clearData();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="filterDropZone">
      <div className="filterIconWrapper">
        <FilterIcon className="filterIcon" />
      </div>
      <div
        className="filterDropZoneInnerDiv"
        onDragOver={(e) => handleDragOver(e)}
        onDrop={(e) => handleDrop(e)}
      >
        <ul>
          {filters.map((filterItem, index, column, type, choices, selectedValues) => (
            <FilterColumnSelector
              key={index}
              index={index}
              column={column}
              namespace={namespace}
              type={type}
              choices={choices}
              selectedValues={selectedValues}
              handleDraggedItem={handleDraggedItem}
              {...filterItem}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Lower child layer:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function FilterColumnSelector({
  selectedColumn,
  handleDraggedItem,
  namespace,
  index,
  column,
  type,
  choices,
  selectedValues,
  //handleDraggedItem,
  ...rest
}) {
  const handleDragStart = (event, column) => {
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text', selectedColumn);
    // handleDraggedItem(event.target.id);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <li key={index} className="draggableColumnList">
        <div
          id={namespace.concat(column)}
          className="draggableColumn"
          draggable="true"
          onDragStart={(event) => handleDragStart(event, column)}
        >
          {column}
        </div>
      </li>
    </>
  );
}
```

The parent component:
// JavaScript source code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './dataExplorer.css';
import AxisDropZone from './axisDraggableArea.js';
import FilterDropZone from './filter/filterDropZone.js';
import DraggableColumnList from './ColumnList/draggableColumnList.js';
import SearchBar from './search/search.js';
import ColourDropZone from './colour/colourDropZone.js';
import SizeDropZone from './size/size.js';

const removeItemFromArray = (item, array) => {
  var index = array.indexOf(item);
  if (index !== -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
  }
  return array;
};

const uniqueValues = (data, column) => {
  var unique = [];
  var distinct = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (!unique[data[i][column]]) {
      distinct.push(data[i][column]);
      unique[data[i][column]] = 1;
    }
  }
  return distinct;
};

export default function DataExplorer({ data, filename }) {
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([]);
  const [childToRemove, setChildToRemove] = useState();
  const [draggedItem, setDraggedItem] = useState();
  const [xaxisColumn, setXaxisColumn] = useState();
  const [yaxisColumn, setYaxisColumn] = useState();
  const [xaxisModification, setXaxisModification] = useState('');
  const [yaxisModification, setYaxisModification] = useState('');
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState();
  const [colourColumn, setColourColumn] = useState();
  const [sizeColumn, setSizeColumn] = useState();
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      if (data.length > 0) {
        setColumns(Object.keys(data[0]));
      }
    }
  }, [data]);

  const handleDraggedItem = (childId) => {
    setDraggedItem(childId);
  };

  const handleXaxisColumn = (newColumn) => {
    setXaxisColumn(newColumn);
  };
  const handleYaxisColumn = (newColumn) => {
    setYaxisColumn(newColumn);
  };

  const handleColourColumn = (newColumn) => {
    setColourColumn(newColumn);
  };

  const handleSizeColumn = (newColumn) => {
    setSizeColumn(newColumn);
  };

  const handleYaxisModification = (newModification) => {
    if (newModification === 'None') {
      setYaxisModification();
    } else {
      setYaxisModification(newModification);
    }
  };
  const handleXaxisModification = (newModification) => {
    setXaxisModification(newModification);
  };

  const handleSearchChange = (newTerm) => {
    setSearchTerm(newTerm);
  };

  const handleRemoveFilter = (columnToRemove) => {
    if (columnToRemove) {
    }
  };

  const handleAddFilter = (columnName) => {
    let newFilters = filters;

    let newFilter = {
      column: columnName,
      type: '',
      choices: ['A', 'B'],
      selectedValues: ['A', 'B']
    };
    if (
      !newFilters.some(function (o) {
        return o['column'] === columnName;
      })
    ) {
      newFilters.push(newFilter);

      setFilters(newFilters);
      console.log(filters);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="data-explorer-container">
      <div className="Data">
        <div className="navigation-container">
          <div className="Navigation"></div>
          <div className="Search-Filter">
            <SearchBar onChange={handleSearchChange} />
          </div>
          <div className="Draggable-Columns">
            <DraggableColumnList
              columns={columns}
              handleDraggedItem={handleDraggedItem}
              searchTerm={searchTerm}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="Colours">
            <ColourDropZone
              draggedItem={draggedItem}
              handleColourColumn={handleColourColumn}
              selectedColumn={colourColumn}
              handleDraggedItem={handleDraggedItem}
              namespace="colour"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="Size">
            <SizeDropZone
              draggedItem={draggedItem}
              handleSizeColumn={handleSizeColumn}
              selectedColumn={sizeColumn}
              handleDraggedItem={handleDraggedItem}
              namespace="size"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="Shapes"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="Graph-Area">
        <div className="Axis-graph-wrapper">
          <div className="Axis-areas">
            <div className="axis-filter-wrapper">
              <div className="FilterZone">
                <FilterDropZone
                  filters={filters}
                  handleAddFilter={handleAddFilter}
                  removeFilter={handleRemoveFilter}
                  handleDraggedItem={handleDraggedItem}
                  namespace="filter"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="AxisZone">
                <div className="axis-wrapper">
                  <div className="XaxisZone">
                    <AxisDropZone
                      handleDraggedItem={handleDraggedItem}
                      draggedItem={draggedItem}
                      selectedColumn={xaxisColumn}
                      handleColumn={handleXaxisColumn}
                      modifications={false}
                      namespace="xaxis"
                      handleModification={handleXaxisModification}
                      axisModification={xaxisModification}
                      axisLabel="x-axis"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="YaxisZone">
                    <AxisDropZone
                      handleDraggedItem={handleDraggedItem}
                      draggedItem={draggedItem}
                      selectedColumn={yaxisColumn}
                      handleColumn={handleYaxisColumn}
                      modifications={true}
                      namespace="yaxis"
                      handleModification={handleYaxisModification}
                      axisModification={yaxisModification}
                      axisLabel="y-axis"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="Graphing-area">
            <div className="graph-container">
              <div className="Yaxis-Label"></div>
              <div className="Graph-Title"></div>
              <div className="Xaxis-Label"></div>
              <div className="Graph"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO!  I suggest taking a look at [how to make a minimally-reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

99% of reactjs questions on SO can be answered with:

1. Lift state up
2. Don't mutate state.

As is often the case, the answer to your question is (2) you are mutating state:

```js
  const handleAddFilter = (columnName) => {
    // this doesn't do anything, newFilters === filters
    let newFilters = filters; 

    let newFilter = {
      column: columnName,
      type: '',
      choices: ['A', 'B'],
      selectedValues: ['A', 'B']
    };
    if (
      !newFilters.some(function (o) {
        return o['column'] === columnName;
      })
    ) {
      // now on this line you are MUTATING state. DON'T MUTATE STATE
      newFilters.push(newFilter);

      // newFilters === filters, so you aren't actually updating the state here, but you have mutated it
      setFilters(newFilters);
      console.log(filters);
    }
  };
```

Rewritten:

```js
  const handleAddFilter = (columnName) => {
    // filter already added, ignore
    if(filters.some(({column}) => column === columnName)) return;

    // add the new filter
    let newFilter = {
      column: columnName,
      type: '',
      choices: ['A', 'B'],
      selectedValues: ['A', 'B']
    };
    setFilters([...filters,newFilter]);
  };
```